# Strange result in firefox14 of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".m").hide();
      $("#home").show();
    });

    function f(id) {
      $(".m").hide();
      $(id).show();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="f(home)"> HOME </a>
  <a href="#" onclick="f(home2)"> HOME2 </a>
  <a href="#" onclick="f(contact)">CONTACT</a>

  <div class="m" id="home">home</div>
  <div class="m" id="home2">home2</div>
  <div class="m" id="contact">contact</div>
</body>
```

In firefox14: Whenever I click on the first `<a>` it doesn't work and the page will be blank. But the others except the first `<a>`(i.e except home) work properly.

But in IE8, all of them work properly.

Why? What's the problem with my code? Is it my problem?

- I want to have some kind of menu that the source of the other page (like contact, about us) are in one page, but they are hidden and by clicking on them, they will be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Firefox has defined the function `window.home`, so it will not refer to the element with `id="home"`. The function is not defined in IE, that's why it's working there.

You shouldn't rely on the elements becoming global variables based on their id. Use a selector to find the elements:

```
<a href="#" onclick="f($('#home'))"> HOME </a>
<a href="#" onclick="f($('#home2'))"> HOME2 </a>
<a href="#" onclick="f($('#contact'))"> CONTACT </a>
```

Alternatively, send the name of the id as a string into the function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="f('home')"> HOME </a>
<a href="#" onclick="f('home2')"> HOME2 </a>
<a href="#" onclick="f('contact')"> CONTACT </a>
```

and make the function use the string instead of an element:

```
function f(id) {
    $(".m").hide();
    $('#' + id).show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function calls are all wrong, using undefined variables instead of strings.

Instead of

```
<a href="#" onclick="f(home)"> HOME </a>
```

It should be

```
<a href="#" onclick="f('#home')"> HOME </a>
```

This has nothing to do with the browser type and version.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your markup to:

```
<a href="#home" class='anchors'> HOME </a>
<a href="#home2" class='anchors'> HOME2 </a>
<a href="#contact" class='anchors'> CONTACT </a>
```

and instead of HTML intrinsic attributes use jQuery `click` method.

```
$('.anchors').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   $('.m').hide()
   $(this.href).show()
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the previous way that I wanted to use, but I got confused. I am new to jquery, what's the usage of passing "e" to function and using e.preventDefault() here?

Comment: @MiladR `e` is `event` object and `preventDefault` prevents the default action of the event.